# Uncaught TypeError: forms.set is not a function

Tags: javascript

Помогите, что за дичь? Уже глаза слипаются, спать хочется, никак с этим не разберусь :(

`Uncaught TypeError: forms.submit is not a function`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Test</title>

    <script>
var forms = {
  lockBtn: function(btn) {

  },

  set: function(type, hide) {
    switch(type) {
      case 1: {
        var forms = document.getElementsByClassName("form");

        for(var i = 0; i < forms.length; i++) {
          forms[i].style.visibility = "hidden";
        }

        document.getElementById("form_first").style.visibility = ((hide) ? "hidden": "visible");
      }
    }
  },

  submit: function(type, btn) {
    switch(type) {
      case 1: {
        var number = document.getElementById("number").value;

        if(!number) {
          return document.getElementById("number").focus();
        }

        this.lockBtn(btn);

        var response = file_get_contents("", "POST", {
            act: "check_available",
            number: number
          },

          function(data) {
            alert(data);
          }
        );
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="form" id="form_first">
  <input type="text" id="number" placeholder="Введите номер..."> 

  <br> <br> 

  <input type="submit" onmousedown="forms.submit(1, this);">
 </div>

 <script>
   window.onload = function() {forms.set(1, false);}
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`forms` возвращает коллекцию форм, в нём нет метода `submit`

```html
<form method='POST'></form>
<form method='GET'></form>
<button onclick='console.log(forms[0].method);'>Форма 1</button>
<button onclick='console.log(forms[1].method);'>Форма 2</button>
```

```js
console.log(document.forms);
```

```html
<form method='POST'></form>
<form method='GET'></form>
```

Comment: Придётся сменить `forms = { }` на что-то другое

Comment: `document.forms`?

Comment: @Qwertiy, он самый

Comment: всё ровно не работает)

Comment: @ikerya, та же самая ошибка?

Comment: да, изменил на `form`, потом вообще на `s`, но ошибка та же

Comment: @ikerya, заменил *forms* на *f* и заработало. Правда ругается на `file_get_contents`, это же с php вроде

Comment: @ikerya, [ТЫДЫЩЬ](http://i.stack.imgur.com/b32wL.png)

Comment: а при клике на кнопку ошибку выдаёт?

Comment: @ikerya, ошибок нет, достаточно в трёх местах заменить

Comment: понял, почему в Вашем примере не фокусится. заменил onmousedown на onclick и заработало, но у меня по прежнему ошибка :| http://prntscr.com/bpgabb и index.php http://prntscr.com/bpgal1

Comment: @ikerya, так `form` тоже самое. Замени на `formz` и потянет [бабах](http://i.stack.imgur.com/7saaN.png)

Comment: заработало, спасибо) тупые дефаулт переменные